# Load Balancing a replicated service in docker swarm in host mode

Tags: docker, webrtc, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have a server that serves a stream over `webrtc` and I have it running as a replicated (either global or replicas) service in a docker swarm.

When I tried running the service in a custom overlay network (swarm scope) the `webrtc` connection always failed. I knew it was networking because the ICE protocol would not retrieve the right candidates and I only had one port exposed and I guess the packets couldn't get inside the overlay network.

Then I put the service running on the host network, there everything works. However, now I don't get the auto load-balancing from docker (so if I make a call to the app on IP x.x.x.x:8080 it will always reach only the replica running on that node).

So how can I load balance a service running on multiple nodes of the swarm but in the host network?

Comment: Docker docs are (surprisingly) silent about this, but I suspected as much: that's the ingress load balancing doesn't happen with `--network host`. Docker doesn't know about what ports are listening?? Anyway, it's great to have a confirmation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the simplest way I found was using an external load balancer like nginx to solve this.

Basically just have nginx also running in a docker container with a config that holds your node IPs for proxying the request, example:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
upstream backend {
   server 192.168.1.2:8080;
   server 192.168.1.3:8080;
   server 192.168.1.4:8080;
   server 192.168.1.5:8080;
   server 192.168.1.6:8080;
}
```